# jquery.uniform.min.js excluding elements

Tags: jquery

I'm playing around with this; http://usman.it/themes/charisma/ template.

It uses jquery.uniform.min.js for styling and I can't turn it off for parts I wish to style manually. This is what they state to do;

```
 // Avoid styling some elements
$("select").not(".skip_these").uniform();  // Method 1
  $('select[class!="skip_these"]').uniform();  // Method 2
```

The html:

```
<input class="skip_these" type="radio" name="test" value="0">
```

This does nothing though. I fear its for the full version uniform.js. In this case uniform.min.js is not started from the  section its referenced

```
<script src="js/jquery.uniform.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting a select tag in your example, and adding a radiobutton as HTML.

Based on your code above, you could change it to something like

```
$('select, input').not('.skip_these').uniform();
```

since a `<select>` != `<input>`.

And just FYI, there's never a difference between a 'full' and a minified version as far as the functionality goes. It's only minified in terms of actual file size.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick responce, that did not work but I managed to find another js file which seemed to have control over sitewide js.

It had this:
       `code`   $("input:checkbox, input:radio, input:file").not('[data-  no-uniform="true"],#uniform-is-ajax').uniform();

All I had to do was add data-no-uniform="true" to the element! I didnt see this anywhere in relation to uniform... thanks very much.